Failed tasks list at the end of the playbook
Is it possible to somehow make it so that, after executing the playbook, at the end it prints all the tasks from the roles that failed, but the playbook was executed due to the ingore_errors option being enabled?
Roles must be included in the playbook as follows:
- name: Playbook
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
  - "../vars/passwords.yml"

  roles:
    - role: ansible-role-1
    - role: ansible-role-2

I tried to do it using post_tasks and I was looking for a collection for it (something like ansible.posix to print at the end of task execution time) but i haven't find a solution

You can achieve this by using Ansible's block feature along with rescue and always blocks. Here's how you can modify your playbook to print failed tasks at the end:
- name: Playbook
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - "../vars/passwords.yml"

  tasks:
    - name: Execute roles with ignore_errors
      block:
        - include_role:
            name: ansible-role-1
          ignore_errors: yes

        - include_role:
            name: ansible-role-2
          ignore_errors: yes

      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "Role {{ ansible_failed_task | default('Unknown Role') }} failed!"

  post_tasks:
    - name: Print failed tasks
      debug:
        msg: "Failed task: {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_playbook_failed_tasks | map(attribute='task_action') | list }}"
      when: ansible_playbook_failed_tasks is defined


This is some way out but it would be best if the playbook structure was left unchanged. i was wondering if there is a callback plugin that does something like this.
Possibly checking which task would not pass if not for the ignore_errors option and adding it to the list and outputting it at the end of the playbook
